# Kartik Select 2 - Programatically changing multiple

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I have a yii2 activeform where the functionality of the form can change based on other things within the form.  So, I have a clubs field, that can be multiple in some instances but not multiple in others.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'clubs')->widget(\kartik\widgets\Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $club_data,
    'hideSearch' => false,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Add Club(s)'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 3,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => 'web/index.php?r=clubs/clubslist',
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }'),
        ],
    ],
])->label('Club(s)'); ?>
```

I need to programmatically change the multiple pluginOption to true and false.  This should be when the user goes into the form but also immediately when a dropdown is changed on the form.  I can do it when the user initially goes into the form but not immediately when another dropdown is changed.

I've made separate fields, one actually linked to a field in the database and another not, this kind of works but it's far from elegant!

I've looked in both the kartik select2 documentation and the standard jquery select2 documentation and I can't spot anything.  Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your comment under my answer renders it totally invalid so I deleted it. Please update your question properly explaining problem in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reference

I was working on a [Yii2-formwizard](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard) plugin a few months back where I had a situation of providing tabular functionality and cloning the fields really became the pain in the ass when it came to using 3rd party plugins like `Select2` and `Datepicker` and I figured out the following code along with a lot of other (as the other part isn't relevant to your problem so not adding it).

### Approach to the problem

The way Kartik-select2 works it stores the select2 plugin-specific options in the `data-krajee-select2` attribute of the element you are using the select2 on.
And the theme or say the Kartik's plugin-specific options like `theme` and others are saved in the variable whose name is saved in the `data-s2-options` attribute. You can look for both of them in view-source of the page where you are using it.

### Solution

So what you need to do is to

#### Steps

- Get the applied options
- Add/Update the option
- Apply back the options

As you just added a single field and not the other one on who's selection it would change, I would demonstrate an example where you can change the behavior of the select2 from `multiple` to `single` using 2 different buttons, clicking on the relevant button the select2 will work accordingly. You can adjust the javascript code where ever you want to.

**But** before I add any code you need to fix one thing, you don't need the main `data` option when you are using the `ajax` option inside the `plugin options`. In other words, it does not have any effect on your select2 and is adding page load time only you should remove it.

You select2 should look like below, I added `id` to the `options` of the select2 for the example you can change it to the active form formatted name like `model-field_name` format if you like, but don't forget to change the id in the javascript code too

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'clubs')->widget(\kartik\widgets\Select2::classname(), [
    'hideSearch' => false,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Add Club(s)','id'=>'clubs'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 3,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => 'web/index.php?r=clubs/clubslist',
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
        ]
    ]
])->label('Club(s)');?>
```

Add the following buttons on your page

```
echo Html::button('multiple', ['class' => 'btn btn-info', 'id' => 'multi']);
echo Html::button('single', ['class' => 'btn btn-info', 'id' => 'single']);
```

And now the magic thing, add it on the top of your view

```
$js = <<<JS
    var element=$("#clubs");
    $('#multi').on('click',function(e){
        //reset select2 values if previously selected 
        element.val(null).trigger('change');

        //get plugin options
        let dataSelect = eval(element.data('krajee-select2'));

        //get kartik-select2 options
        let krajeeOptions = element.data('s2-options');

        //add your options
        dataSelect.multiple=true;

        //apply select2 options and load select2 again
        $.when(element.select2(dataSelect)).done(initS2Loading("clubs", krajeeOptions));
    });

    $('#single').on('click',function(e){
        element.val(null).trigger('change');
        let dataSelect = eval(element.data('krajee-select2'));
        let krajeeOptions = element.data('s2-options');
        dataSelect.multiple=false;
        $.when(element.select2(dataSelect)).done(initS2Loading("clubs", krajeeOptions));
    });
JS;

$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Now if your select2 is working correctly click on the <kbd>multiple</kbd> button and you will see the multiple selections are enabled for the select2 and when clicked on the <kbd>single</kbd> button.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Muhammad - Thanks for the reply and sorry it took so long to get back to this, I got sidetracked!  It's awesome, just what I wanted.  One thing I should mention is that I need the data field.  The form is used for creating and updating.  On update, if the main data isn't there, I just see the ID's of the clubs, not the name.

Comment: @Mike you should use the `initValueText` option and provide the saved values for the multiselect like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694113/yii2-select2-how-to-set-initvaluetext-in-gridview-or-tabularform)

Comment: Hi Muhammad - I was thinking of keeping the $data but selecting out only the ones that are in the record it's trying to display.  I'm guessing you're solution works much better  ;-)  Thanks so much.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Im sorry out of topic, but how to modifty data options throught js like this?
I have same situations but what I need is change the data options instead multiple/single select optiions..

Thanks very much..

Comment: @Hallaz i dont quite get your question what you mean by **modify the data options** are you talking about changing the dropdown options that are provided via `data` option in select2