# Yii2 clone select 2 widget

Tags: yii2, widget, jquery-select2

I had used kartik select2 widget for select multiple product, Now want to clone that product select2 in same form.

After clone that product select2 not working. I know problem is unique id but i dont know which id generate problem. after generate clone i had change following attributes value.

1. id
2. data-select2-id
3. data-s2-options
4. data-krajee-select2

Can anyone help to solve this ?

Comment: this answer relates to what you want to do and why is it not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57737968/yii2-using-select2-with-tabular-step-of-yii2-formwizard/57739647#57739647

Comment: also you need to read here why the cloned select2 doesnot work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159631/kartik-select-2-programatically-changing-multiple/57172881#57172881